# Choosing one row over another, but not based on the where clause

Tags: mysql

Not quite sure how to ask this properly, which is perhaps part of my problem. There exists a database with many similar records differentiated by a column called 'priority'. I'd like to grab the record with the higher priority which has the same 'type' & 'project' id. For example, the table looks like this:

```
id  project_id type_id  priority 
1   66          14      0
2   66          14      10
3   66          16      0
```

Currently the program selects via project and type:

```
Select * FROM table WHERE project_id = 66;
```

And then it loops through the results and discards the lower priority record when there exists multiple records of the same `type_id`. Is there a way to do this via the select?

The ideal result set would be:

```
id  project_id type_id  priority 
2   66          14      10
3   66          16      0
```

Where it discarded the lower priority type_id 14 record. There may be more then 2 items with the same type_id in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM table GROUP BY project_id, type_id ORDER BY priority DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
JOIN (
    SELECT project_id, type_id, MAX(priority) AS max_priority
    FROM table
    GROUP BY project_id, type_id
) AS maxima -- subquery returns one row per group (project_id, type_id) along with the highest priority in each group 
-- join this with the main table
ON maxima.project_id = table.project_id
AND maxima.type_id = table.type_id
AND maxima.max_priority = table.priority
```

Comment: If several rows have a priority equal to the maximum priority, this will return them all. I'm feeling lazy right now, so I'll try to get rid of these "duplicates" only if you ask me to ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only field that is difficult to get is the `id`.  And, you can use a `group_concat()` trick to get that.

```
select project_id, type_id, max(priority) as priority,
       substring_index(group_concat(id order by priority desc), ',', 1) as id
from t
group by project_id, type_id;
```

This will ensure that you get the id for the maximum, and that you only get one such row for each `project_id`/`type_id` combination.